# Is it possible to delay a systemd service indefinitely by "After" clause?

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

Currently I am working on this issue:
Service 1 is on another machine.
Service 2 is on this machine but need Service 1 available to function.
Service 3 is on this machine but need Service 2 to function.

I want to make two automatic starting systemd service for Service 2 and Service 3.

The script to start service 2 firstly check if service 1 is available, and if not, it will be stuck in check/sleep while loop until found Service 1.

Then I want to add
`After=Service_3.service` in `Service_2.service`

or
`Before=Service_2.service` in `Service_3.service`

And I set `Service_2.service`'s type as `oneshot`

So will systemd indefinitely postpone starting Service 3 until Service 2 has found Service 1 available?

BTW: I do not need to restart Service 2 once it is down, for Service 3 is the High Availability program specially designed to take care of it, but it is required to run after starting Service 2.